# Playing Chess via SMS Messaging

Tags: command-line, shell, sms, email

I know there are some pretty nice open-source chess engines with powerful AI, like [Crafty](http://www.craftychess.com/), that also have a nifty command line interface.

I also know that I can send e-mails with my SMS-capable phone, and that I can reply to such an e-mail, and it will be sent to my phone as a SMS text message.

Is there any way I can combine the two?  For example, text message a command like "Nd3" to an e-mail monitored by a computer, which sends the command to Crafty, and e-mails back the response?

I wasn't sure which site to post this one on; hopefully this is appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of parsing emails back and forth, you could use one of the SMS gateways out there like [Twilio](http://twilio.com) that supports sending and receiving messages via HTTP POST requests. I don't know of any free ones off hand that do it this way, but using regular ol' HTTP could save you a lot of time fussing with email servers and such.

Full disclosure: I work at Twilio.

Comment: What framework would I set this up on?  I'm not exactly sure where to start; would I use an API and a scripting language like ruby/python/bash, and attach it to my chess engine?

Thanks

Comment: Any framework that supports sending/receiving HTTP requests. We have helper libraries for a bunch of them including Ruby and Python: http://github.com/twilio

Comment: hm; this sounds like a very nice solution.  If I ever decide to go commercial with this application, I would definitely do it.

However, this is for my own personal hobby and chess playing =/